# Difference between the maximum of a guage metric and instances with a label a series

Tags: prometheus, promql

I have a prometheus guage metric (`height`) that I have a number of instances of with a regex-able label (`pod_name`) that I want to take the maximum of and subtract from each instance to get the difference between it and the maximum.

What I thought would work would be something like:

```
height{pod_name=~"a-name.*"} - max(height{pod_name=~"a-name.*"})
```

Where the individual parts work, but subtracting fails.

Any ideas on this query?  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
height{pod_name=~"a-name.*"} - on() group_left() max(height{pod_name=~"a-name.*"})
```

See [these docs](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#many-to-one-and-one-to-many-vector-matches) for details on `on()` and `group_left()` modifiers.